# CAShapeLayer strokeColor from image pattern UIColor to CGColor upside down

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, calayer, cashapelayer

I'm using `CABasicAnimation` to draw all `UIBezierPaths` i have in an Array using `CAShapeLayer`

```
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];    
shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
shapeLayer.strokeColor = path.color.CGColor;
```

My `path.color` is a `UIColor` from image pattern. When it is converted to `CGColor` the `image pattern` is upside down. I know that is because iOS and core graphics use different starting points for drawing.

I have tried

```
shapeLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

and

```
shapeLayer.geometryFlipped = YES;
```

But none of them worked.

How do I flip the `strokeColor` image pattern 180 degree to match with the origin `UIColor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have correctly suspected, the coordinate system differs. In this case, the origin is at the bottom left at `(0, 0)`.

So what you could do to compensate that is to either flip the image yourself using an image editor or do it in code like so:

```
UIImage *flippedPatternImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:patternImage.CGImage scale:1.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored];

UIColor *colorWithImagePattern = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:flippedPatternImage];
```

And finally assign it to the `strokeColor`:

```
shapeLayer.strokeColor = path.color.CGColor;
```

Comment: Your code didn't flip the image. I had to redraw the image upsidedown using core graphics.

Comment: @imObjCSwifting Since you didn't show how you define your `path`, it would be helpful and clearer if you would show the part how to define it (`UIBezierPath`), which doesn't have a `property` color, _especially_ If you are subclassing `UIBezierPath` yourself (I wouldn't do that). I have used the code for `CALayer` myself.